# prevent php access and include for files in parent directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, file-permissions, directory-permissions

Is it possible to prevent PHP from including or accessing files which are below a certain directory via htaccess or something else? In this case both User 1 and User 2 have direct access to their folder via FTP but unfortunately I cannot provide them with an independent PHP platform to work on. Is there anything I could do to avoid user1 to do something like this “../user2” within his files or even worse accessing the other website “../../website1”?

```
/root
/root/website1
/root/website2
/root/website2/users
/root/website2/users/user 1 [..]
/root/website2/users/user 2 [..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the ownership and group of those two directories to the relevant user, and limit permissions to the owner/group of the directory (basically, remove rwx from others on their directories).

This will need further configuration in the Apache virtualhost to specify which 'user' Apache should read the relevant document root as of : [mod_suexec » suexecusergroup](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_suexec.html#suexecusergroup)

You probably should set your server umask to 007 to maintain this restriction on all new files/folders.

Additionally, I'd set the SETGID bit on all folders in your web-root `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;`

Comment: This won't actually work in most cases, as PHP often runs as the Apache user.

Comment: By The Appropriate user, I think he means the user that Apache Uses. And doing that will work, because then PHP will have no access to the file.

Comment: Setting the right configuration in Apache means that PHP will be called by whatever user you want - even on a per site basis.